# Google Translate API for Localizing my App

Tags: java, android, google-translate

just need to clear a doubt. Can we use google translate api for localising our app.

Means i created my app using English language and in playstore i released it for worldwide users.

Now i want that for each country when they install and open my app will the google translate api will convert the app language to their native language if i integrate this api to my app.

Eg. - For India, the app should be opened in English language.
For France, the app should be opened in French language.

"The UI text should get converted"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use Translate API; you'd have to do this on a computer,

parse the default resource XML from `values/strings.xml` (English)

and then write to `values-in/strings.xml` or `values-fr/strings.xml`.

one could use `PHP` or `NodeJS`; but the results may vary - and might not match the context within the screen (as someone who translated quite some software, can only tell that this may play a huge role).

there also is an [App Translation Service](https://support.google.com/l10n/answer/6341304?hl=en) ...

Answer (score 2):

No.  And even if you could, you wouldn't want to-  automatic translation is just not very good.  What you can do is Google Play has a method to hire translators through Google Play, who know how to localize strings.xml files.  That's worth looking into.